# Connecting database in app without show interface at website

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new developing android and web apps, I would like to know if is it possible to connect a mySQL DB already hosted in a website provide by phpmyadmin plataform just creating an interface to the  android app? 'cause I just want to host the DB on the DNS to acess inside the app and don't want to show any interface if someone try to acess my DNS

if possible please explain details how am I able to get this, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Mysql` Database which is in hosted in your website by using `Php` progrmamming.

For this Read [`How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL`](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

or otherwise you just do the following.

```
 1) create db file 
 2) host the db file in database.
 3) download the db file to the device and you can use that db file.
```

Have a good luck..

Comment: download to the device is not an option for what I want, but thanks anyway, I will research on the link

Comment: i just suggest you the way.Its your opinion to choose or not.